# "Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) provider" and "Java update" issue

Tags: java, cryptography

We developed our own JCA-provider. We installed it and registered using "Static Registration" procedure (as described in ["Installing Providers"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderInstalling)). But when the Java stared automatic update process he failed with following error:

[image]

Does anybody know what happened and how we need to install/register our JCA-provider to prevent such an error?

**UPDATE**

After this warning Java update fails and **java can't work anymore**. JRE return the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I registered this problem as **BUG**. But Oracle BUG-tracking system work very bad. I even can't look at the bug status and vote for him... Please vote for this BUG if BUG-tracking will be alive:

Monitor this bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7061353

Voting for the bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/addVote.do?bug_id=7061353

Comment: I still can't view my registered BUG... I think Oracle support can work better...

Comment: The BUG is on the Oracle BUG-tracking... at last! Please, vote for him.

Comment: This BUG is in top25. I think Oracle need to do something to solve the issuer.

Answer (score 3):

May be I am misunderstanding your post, but I do not see a problem here.
The `java.security` file contains all the runtime configuration for security e.g. Providers, OCSP, SSLFactory etc.
You can add a new provider in this file (static configuration) or add it dynamically via `Security.addProvider` (I personally prefer dynamically).
In your case you added the custom provider in the `java.security` file at the prefered position, and I assume you verified it works.
Now during the java update, the update process "understood" that the `java.security` file is no longer the default file delivered in a default installation (and this is correct since you have added your custom provider and possibly other configuration options?) and did not copy the default java.security file to avoid overiding yours.
If you open the java.security file you should see your file containing your provider.
So the warning just says that your custom `java.security` file is left unchanged.
**Note:** IMHO it is better to use dynamic registration so that your security is controlled by your app and does not depend on configuration file being set correctly.But this is my opinion.

Comment: Which also illustrates another benefit of dynamic registration.

Comment: @ user384706 after this warning Java update fails. And java can not run anymore...

Comment: @ user384706 thanks, but we can't use dynamic registration by the requirements.

Comment: @Sasha:It could be a bug. See a similar post here:http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1315956&tstart=1 Perhaps you should report this to SUN?

Comment: @user384706 I think you are right. This is the bug: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2246232. Maybe someone from SUN/ORACLE can help...

Comment: @Sasha:Report this and in the meantime you could follow the suggesion in the http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1315956&tstart=1 which suggests:revert the file, upgrade and modify the file

Comment: @user384706 I restored the JRE by downloading the 26 version of java and installed it manually. I can not report the BUG, because Oracle bug tracking system is DOWN at this moment... maybe they have another biggest BUG.